# How do I get missed classes from JaCoCo?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, jacoco

I have a mixed Java/Kotlin project, and after a failed build the report says:

```
Loading execution data file jacoco.exec
Analyzed bundle 'xxx-api' with 884 classes
[WARNING] Rule violated for bundle xxx-api: classes missed count is 36, but expected maximum is 35
```

This is my local build, and it fails in Jenkins too (with the same error), so I need to solve this locally (I mean, I can't change nothing about the environment nor the pom.xml), so I was wondering if there's a way to know what are the missed classes.

This is a part of the report:

[image]

And this is what appears in the bottom:

[image]

So, the "36 missed classes" aren't the sum of the missed column, and I don't get how to know what are the missed classes.

Is it any way to know it?